# UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent not working

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, uiappearance

When I use this:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "brown")
```

I get a nav bar that has the correct brown and it is translucent.

[image: nav bar with translucent brown]

But I don't want it to be translucent, I just want it to be my brown color. So, I add another line of code to change the appearance to turn off the translucency, and instead of getting a solid brown, it just gives me the default white.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "brown")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

[image: nav bar all white]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree completely. Leave `isTranslucent` alone! Do not set any navigation bar properties directly! Use UINavigationBarAppearance to perform your configuration. For example:

```
let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
app.backgroundColor = .brown
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = app
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = app
```

Comment: Ah, this new thing was added in iOS 13 and I didn't realize it. Thanks!

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/the-ios-developers-guide-to-ios14/ for a list of things you may have missed.

Comment: What if I want to do it for only one viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "brown")
```

I think changing only `backgroundColor` is not enough in this case.